# Import stylesheet with php if a certain page is requested

Tags: php, css, import, include

I would like to import a css stylesheet in a page depending on a php condition (or other), this condition is based upon the domain URL.

For example, if the page loaded is "mydomain.com/about-us" import a "css/about-us.css" file.

I have tried with this code, but it does not work.

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strstr($url, "mydomain.com/about-us/")) {
        include '/css/about-us.css'; 
    }
?>
```

How can I import, or use a `<style>` tag conditionally?

**solution correct:**

the correct solution is use only the page name, so if you page is mydomain.com/about-us/

use " /about-us/" only.

now have other question, with the code posted you can import css for specific page , but  I noticed that if the domain is mydomain.com/about-us/team.html example in the page team.html load also the css of "about-us" how load the css for about-us only in the page mydomain/about-us/ ??

Comment: Could you give some more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: hi, i want use a php script for load  different css file in according to page URL loaded , i have tried the code posted but not function, also in source page (after load )the css not compare, how do I fix?

Comment: Why can't you embed the css file in the page?

Comment: because the site use 2 principal php page template, for every page type change only the file load in this page, so i request have specific css for specific page URL

Comment: Why didn't the code posted work?

Comment: I honestly do not know, only works the code of "Nikos M.", but  returns the css of 'else' condition .probably can not compare the variable domain

Comment: thanks have solved with use only the page name without domain, but now have other question , i have update my first question, please read

Comment: I've updated my answer again.

Comment: perfect this code works

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted with the check mark if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a stylesheet to the page with PHP by including this in the `<head>` of your html document:

```
<?php
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $file . '">';
?>
```

Where `$file` is the name of the css file. You're going to have to provide some more information as to what you're trying to do for a better answer.

#### Update

The variable `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` only gives the requested page, not the whole domain. From the PHP manual,

> 'REQUEST_URI'
>       The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

So the code should look as follows:

```
<?php
    $requested_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($requested_page === "/about-us" || $requested_page === "/about-us/") {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/about-us.css">';
    }
?>
```

This will test if the requested page is "/about-us" (the client is requesting the "about-us" page) and if it does, the link to the stylesheet will be echoed.

Answer (score 3):

How you can read [here](http://php.net/strstr), `strstr` will return a string or FALSE. You can change it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<?php
if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "mydomain.com/about-us/")!=false) {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/about-us.css">';
} ?>
</head>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Or:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<?php
if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "mydomain.com/about-us/")!=false) {
echo file_get_contents('/css/about-us.css');
} ?>
</style>
</head>
...
</body>
</html>
```

In the first example your CSS is included through the `<link>` tag, in the second, the PHP-script loads your CSS file into the `script`-tags. You can not use `include` because it will load another php file and execute where it was included. You should use my first example, because it is more server-friendly because the CSS file doesn't need to be read. Your page will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strstr($url, "mydomain.com/about-us/")) 
    {
        // output an HTML css link in the page
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/about-us.css" />'; 
    }
   else
   {
        // output an HTML css link in the page
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/another.css" />'; 
   }
?>
```

you can also do this to import the css contents directly, but probably some media/images links can break:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strstr($url, "mydomain.com/about-us/")) 
    {
        // output css directly in the page
        echo '<style type="text/css">' .file_get_contents('./css/about-us.css').'</style>'; 
    }
   else
   {
        // output css directly in the page
        echo '<style type="text/css">' .file_get_contents('./css/another.css').'</style>'; 
   }
?>
```